# ¿Cómo ocultar columnas de una tabla a un usuario en Oracle?

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle

Existe alguna manera de ocultar ciertas columnas a un usuario en Oracle, quise usar la sentencia:

```
 GRANT SELECT (nombre) ON prueba TO prueba;
```

Pero me marca un error

> ORA-00969: falta la palabra clave ON

Comment: También utilice la sentencia GRANT SELECT ON prueba (nombre) TO prueba; y no me ha funcionado

Comment: La sintaxis es `GRANT [privilegio] ON [objeto] TO [usuario];`, pero esto no sirve para ocultar columnas... ¿Cuál es tu pregunta en realidad? ¿Como hacer un grant o cómo ocultar las columnas?

Comment: ¿Cómo ocultar las columnas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La forma más simple de darle acceso a un usuario a una tabla y NO mostrar ciertas columnas es crear una vista:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW [nombre_de_vista] AS
    SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL5 --No incluyes la columna que no quieres que vean
    FROM [tabla_original];
```

Lo que hace esto es crear una tabla lógica que puede ser consultada por los usuarios de la misma forma que lo harían con una tabla. Una vista no contiene data en sí, por lo que no afectará en mucho al uso de espacio en la BD.

Luego de crear esta vista, simplemente puedes otorgar el acceso como lo harías con una tabla normal

```
GRANT SELECT ON [nombre_de_vista] TO [schema];
```

Comment: Ok, lo haré de esta manera, gracias